# Jersey JSON and Date

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I have a problem with parsing JSON to Date object.

I use Jersey 1.14, Tomcat 7.

My Resource class:

```
    @Path("/user")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public class UserResource {
        @Path("/~/update")
        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response updateUser(User user) {
            // There are update in DB
            // but Date field always null
            return Response.ok().build();
        }
        @Path("/~/get")
        @GET
        public User getUser() {
            // There are I fetch User from DB
            // Works fine, User instance returns in correct JSON
            return user;
        }

    }
```

My Model:

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
    @XmlRootElement(name = "user")
    public class User {
        @XmlElement(name = "name")
        private String name;
        @XmlElement(name = "myDate")
        @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
        private Date myDate;
        // Getters and Setters
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public Date getMyDate() {
            return myDate;
        }
        public void setMyDate(Date myDate) {
            this.myDate = myDate;
        }
    }
```

My XmlAdapter for Date class:

```
    public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

        private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy-MM-dd");

        @Override
        public String marshal(Date v) {
            return dateFormat.format(v);
        }

        @Override
        public Date unmarshal(String v) {
            try {
                return dateFormat.parse(v);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new WebApplicationException();
            }
        }
    }
```

Why in my POST method always null Date field? 
This JSON I am trying to send:

```
{"name":"Peter","myDate":"1988-05-31"}
```

P.S. sorry for my bad English.

**UPD.**
My client code:

```
    public class Tester {

        public static void main(String... args) throws FileNotFoundException, JSONException {

            Client c = Client.create();
            WebResource r = c.resource("http://localhost:8080/myapp/user/~/get");
            ClientResponse resp = r.get(ClientResponse.class);
            JSONObject entity = resp.getEntity(JSONObject.class);
            entity.remove("myDate");
            entity.put("myDate", "1988-05-31");
            r = c.resource("http://localhost:8080/myapp/user/~/update");
            resp = r.entity(entity, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class);
            entity = resp.getEntity(JSONObject.class);
            System.out.println(entity);
        }
    }
```

**UPD 2.**

I found a very stupid mistake in my app.
Instead *java.util.Date* I used *java.sql.Date* in my Model class :( 
Thats why Date field always was null.

Comment: Could you post client code of sending JSON?

Comment: Thank you for your question. I posted client code.

Comment: I follow the code and write a demo, but i doesn't work. It seems that DateAdapter is ignored directly.  I also asked a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17057150/xmljavatypeadapter-doesnt-work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server code are right. The error is in your client code:

```
resp = r.entity(entity, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class);
```

should be:

```
resp = r.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class,entity);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Unfortunately, it's not worked for me.
What the difference on these methods?
After looking API documentation I decided that there are no differences in these two methods.

Comment: Sorry for my not careful test. I test your code in my environment again, It works well. In updateUser method, the user argument is right. Can you post your web.xml?

Answer (score -2):

You have to serialize/deserialize the date or you have to make the Date String.

```
private String myDate;
```