# @XmlJavaTypeAdapter doesn't work

Tags: java, jersey

I got the bug http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-288, but it said the bug should have been fixed in the version 1.6.2.

I refer to lots of threads, like,
[Jersey JSON and Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611665/jersey-json-and-date)
[How to convert Date(ActionScript 3) to java.util.Date through a xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687188/how-to-convert-dateactionscript-3-to-java-util-date-through-a-xml/4694496#4694496)

I tried version 1.12, 1.14, 1.17.1, all can't works in my side.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="info")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class InfoVO  { 
    private int infoId;
    @XmlElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
    private Date createTime;
//...get/set

}

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) {
        return dateFormat.format(v);
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) {
        try {
            return dateFormat.parse(v);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new WebApplicationException();
        }
    }
}


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But that the DateAdapter can't be called at all, and got a exception,

2013-06-12 11:11:13.363:WARN::/xa/info/save/12121: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2013-06-08 08:00:00': not a valid representation (error: Can not parse date "2013-06-08 08:00:00": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))| at [Source: java.io.StringReader@b0ff5e1; line: 8, column: 23] (through reference chain: com.xchange.me.vo.InfoVO["createTime"])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the root cause, as I added a customized MessageBodyReader,

```
  @Provider
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public class CustomJsonReader<T> implements MessageBodyReader<T> {
        @Override
        public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
            return true;
        }

    @Override
    public T readFrom(Class<T> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders,
            InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        /*
         * Copy the input stream to String. Do this however you like. Here I use
         * Commons IOUtils.
         */
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(entityStream, writer, "UTF-8");
        String json = writer.toString();

        /*
         * if the input stream is expected to be deserialized into a String,
         * then just cast it
         */
        if (String.class == genericType)
            return type.cast(json);

        /*
         * Otherwise, deserialize the JSON into a POJO type. You can use
         * whatever JSON library you want, here's a simply example using GSON.
         */
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.readValue(json, type);
    }
    }
```

So when received the json data, always come into the readFrom method, and then threw exception in the line return objectMapper.readValue(json, type);

So I think the root cause is ObjectMapper.readValue ignore the annotation @XmlJavaTypeAdapter

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Finally, I removed the CustomJsonReader, and then it works.